# Apps Script Slow Output

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, nested-loops

I am having problems creating an attendance tracker for my job. Specifically, I am trying to create some analysis metrics; the one I'm having a problem with is finding a total sum of days present for each person. It's been a long time since I've done any real coding, so I'm quite sure my code is very ugly and hobbled together.

Here is how my data is structured: (1 means present, 0 means absent)

| Week Ending | Day | Person1 | Person2 | Person 3 | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/29/23 | Monday | 1 | 1 | 0 | ... |
|  | Tuesday | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |
|  | Wednesday | 0 | 1 | 1 | ... |
|  | Thursday | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... |
|  | Friday | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
|  | Notes |  |  | Sick | ... |
| 10/6/23 | Monday | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... |
|  | Tuesday | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... |
|  | Wednesday | 0 | 1 | 1 | ... |
|  | Thursday | 1 | 0 | 1 | ... |
|  | Friday | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
|  | Notes |  |  |  | ... |

And so on and so forth. Originally, I didn't have the notes rows in there, so I was able to just sum down the column. But after I added that, it became a little more difficult to avoid the NaN errors.

My code currently looks like this:

```
  for (i = 0; i < roster.length; i++) {
    totals1.push(archive.getRange(1, 3+i).getValue()); // totals[0] contains names
    var sum = 0;
    var x = 1;
    while (archive.getRange(1+x, 2).getDisplayValue() != "") {
      if (archive.getRange(2+x, 3+i).getDisplayValue().length == 1) { // comment strings will have longer 
        sum += +archive.getRange(2+x, 3+i).getDisplayValue();         // lengths than 1 so they won't be included
      }
      x++;
    }
    totals2.push(sum); // totals[1] contains sum
  }
  totals.push(totals1, totals2);
  var totals2d = []
  for (i = 0; i < roster.length; i++) {
    totals2d[i] = [totals[0][i], totals[1][i]]; //combine both arrays to make 2d array
  }
```

The code works, my problem is, though, it takes about 4 mins to work. the roster.length is currently 60, and our workforce is expected to expand, which would make the wait even longer. I'm honestly struggling with comprehending why it's so computationally slow. There's several other places in my code where I use nested loops and it all completes within a few seconds.

If anybody can help me speed this up I would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample sheet with dummy values for us to further replicate why your script is running slow?

Comment: As written in the linked duplicate, you  shouldn't use getRange inside the loop.

Comment: Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455), which make the question useless for others or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files. cc:@CenturyTuna